# Two domains points to the same directory (Apache)

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have two domains,

1. hovelgps.in
2. quicktrack.in

I created virtual hosts in Apache with different directories, but when I go to the second domain it will redirect to the first domains directory.

My `httpd.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hovelgps.in
    ServerAlias hovelgps.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hovelgps.in
    ErrorLog /var/www/hovelgps.in/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/hovelgps.in/requests.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quicktrack.co
    ServerAlias quicktrack.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/quicktrack.co
    ErrorLog /var/www/quicktrack.co/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/quicktrack.co/requests.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 7):

Your second VirtualHost is configured with `quicktrack.co` and not the domain from your question `quicktrack.in` so which should it be?

When an unconfigured domainname is used, Apache will use the first VirtualHost as the default.

Second, more a style issue and not a configuration error, but  normally the `ServerAlias` hostnames are different from the hostname in The `ServerName` directive. I would expect something like `ServerAlias www.hovelgps.in`

Comment: Third (not worth an answer of its own, but might be worth a mention in yours), OP is exposing both the error log and the request log through the DocumentRoot. Probably not the best idea, especially now that the domain names *and* file names are known...

Comment: fourth, none of your comments is an answer for this question. Add the second domain to the etc/hosts and/or check the chowner and chmod of the second website's directory. both should have the same properties if the first one is working.